# connecting oscillators in parallel to increase current

Tags: transistors, oscillator, parallel, coil

I am trying to power an alternating current coil, and was wondering if I can connect the output from transistor oscillators in parallel to increase the current, like you can with batteries. I don't need to increase voltage, just current.

Comment: That seems silly. For one thing, you need them to be in phase. Use one oscillator and a power amp.

Comment: help us all Delta1X . .  Many things can be parallel to increase capability.  What type of oscillators are you considering? Generally paralleling circuits requires a little more information until we can help you. Also, please define better what you mean by "alternating current coil"

Comment: Okay, by alternating current coil I mean an electromagnet fed by a alternating current, to produce a varying electromagnetic field. I was thinking about using a colpitts or hartley oscillator, basically anything that doesn't use crystals. The idea was to connect the oscillators in parallel to increase the current/ ampere-turns. I could use an amplifier, but if I can I would rather build it out of salvaged pieces to save money, since it is a experimental design for a research project, and I would rather not blow some pricey high current transistor amplifiers.

Comment: you nailed it KAZ.  You should have posted as an "answer", rather than comment" regarding the phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good help in your comment Delta1X.  Now some help can be had.

In general, you can parallel any voltage source, as long as you take steps for them to share equally.  You might need to add buffer stage to the output of an oscillator. This would keep any loading effects from affecting the frequency of the oscillator.

Additionally, you might need to use a small bit of resistance in series with the output of the buffered oscillator to help with sharing of the load on the oscillator.

If you get to specifics of oscillators,  more info can be had to help you.

And as KAZ said,  if you buffer the oscillator, you only need one oscillator.

Comment: The important point in Kaz's answer is not the buffering, but the the fact that every oscillator must be in sync in order to generate a controllable and deterministic output.  If the OP plans on doing anything useful other than random outputs, it would be much (by orders of magnitude) more costly/harder to synchronize correctly the oscillators so they do not fight each other.  Since you answer mostly makes sense, I am not down-voting this, but it doesn't deserve being up-voted unless you change that because this is where it would get "silly".

Comment: @Mishyoshi. .  Thanks.  But if you will also notice my comment on the original question above, you will see I also credited Kaz with his "in phase" comment. I was directly answering the question, without adding to it.

Comment: @Mishyoshi . .  I always attempt to first directly answer a question.  Later get into areas where the OP might be going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, you looked like you read too fast his comment and though that he was saying that buffering would solve the problem, which is definitely not true.  I actually prefer to answer both the question and what the OP might really want to do, so that someone else having the same problem may use a valid solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody! All input was very helpful.

Comment: All comments and the answer were helpful, unfortunately I cannot upvote comments, but thank you all!